# JavaScript regex construction

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

To test which mathematical operator (*, /, +, -) exists in the following items:

```
13*4
7+8
-15/3
7-5
```

I have the following regex for JavaScript:

```
/[\*\+/\-]/
```

The problem is that regex will identify the *negative* sign in `-15/3` as an operator. How do I make it NOT match on first character in the string?

Comment: also, this is a valid statement `5--5`.

Comment: Eish, getting complicated... but true. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: if you can add spaces before and after operators then this will be simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match a regex like this:

```
One or more digits (also allowing a decimal)
followed by optional whitespace 
followed by an operator 
followed by optional whitespace 
followed by one or more digits (also allowing a decimal)
```

and then reference the captured group in the middle to get just the operator:

```
/[\d.]+\s*([*+\-\/])\s*[\d.]+/
```

Sample code:

```
var match = str.match(/[\d.]+\s*([*+\-\/])\s*[\d.]+/);
if (match) {
    var operator = match[1];
}
```

Working demo and test code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DgrSg/

---

If you want to allow more than just digits before the operators (such as other expressions), then you will have to do a lot more than a simple or even complex regex.  This answer assumes you're just trying to solve the examples that you've presented.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
/.[\*\+/\-]/
```

which just ensures there's a character in front of the symbol.

That's a pretty quick and dirty fix, I'd probably prefer to make a full expression evaluator to catch the hundred other potential error conditions but it'll do if you want something simple and only marginally more robust than what you have.

Comment: From what I understand, the . means any character. Is it possible to limit the leading character to a number by simply using `//d[\*\+/\-]/` ?

Comment: @Jimbo, yes, though it's `\d` rather than `/d`. But you should really _consider_ the idea of a proper expression evaluator since a regex doesn't give you the full power - there'll almost always be more edge cases you have to worry about :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your operator is preceded by a digit and followed by either a digit or a minus sign and a digit.

```
/\d[\*\+/\-]-?\d/
```